# dismissGrantingAccessToURL of UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController is not working

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

I am working on document provider extension for import mode.

URL of file is sitting inside the shared container shared by both extension & container app.

I got assertion failure saying that it should sit inside shared container/File Provider Storage directory.

So I copied file from original directory to File Provider Storage directory.

I have a file in original location & I got a file in new copied location also. I checked for data length of the file also, Its proper ,

But when I call [self dismissGrantingAccessToURL:toUrl];

Its not dismissing `UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController`,

I am not facing any exceptions , but it wont dismiss and initiate the transfer, So user can still access the extension.

Below is my code, If anyone came across the same thing please leave your reply.

```
- (void)userChoosesEntityOfUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURL *toUrl = [self.documentStorageURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[toUrl path]]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[toUrl path] error:nil];
    }
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:url toURL:toUrl error:nil]) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [toUrl path]);
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[toUrl path]]) {
        NSLog(@"File Doesn't exists at this path");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Data Length %i",[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[toUrl path]] length]);

    [self dismissGrantingAccessToURL:toUrl];
}
```

Comment: Please try with Xcode6.1 beta.

Answer (score 2):

When debugging your implementation of `NSFileProviderExtension`, you usually end up stopping/killing it using Xcode. After this, iOS often has problems restarting your file extension. This results in your document picker not being dismissed after calling `dismissGrantingAccessToURL:`. This bug also affects your subclass of `UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController` which sometimes won't start (you only see the navigation bar of the document picker but not the content).

The workaround is to reboot your device.

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if you have a backing File Provider extension that has not been fully implemented. Remove the File Provider target from your embedded extension phase, set your document extension only support import/export modes in the Info.plist, and do a product -> Clean before building and running your extension.

Comment: This is not changing anything for me ... Note that I also have the exact same issue with the "NewBox" sample app !

Comment: I've created my project again, and when I've added the "Document provider" target, I've unchecked the "Include a File Provider extension" checkbox. I don't know if it's related to that, but now it's working !